# Associating a service fabric cluster subnet to NSG

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azureportal

Azure portal is not showing the nodes after associating the service fabric cluster subnet to the NSG.

Before the cluster subnet is associated to the NSG:

[image]

After the cluster subnet is associated to NSG:
[image]

Am I missing something or is this a bug on portal?

Comment: What's an NSG? Also, how did you do this? Was it powershell? If so, can you add the commands in. At the moment it's a bit of a non question

Comment: The NSG stands for network security group. I did the assignment on portal. You have to go to NSG resource -> Settings -> subnets -> associate. Find the cluster subnet and associate it to NSG. Then go to cluster and check are the nodes available... Even though nodes are not shown on cluster view the cluster is working. Also rules set on NSG are doing their work as configured.

Comment: @JPKK I Do I need to associate Network Interfaces to the NSG too or just subnets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to ensure that you have whitelisted the proper ports via the NSG rules. [I discuss some of this here](https://brentdacodemonkey.wordpress.com/2016/08/01/network-isolationsecurity-with-azure-service-fabric/).

The short list is (as best I've been able to determine so far):
19080, 19000 for external access. and 1025-1027, 49152-65534, and 445 within the cluster's vnet.

Comment: I was missing 19000 and 19080 rules, I whitelisted them and now the portal is working as it should! Thanx. Btw, Excellent "Notepad" you have!